# boost::asio performant serial read (RS232)

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, boost-asio

I have the following method (located in a class) taken from: https://gitorious.org/serial-port/serial-port/source/03e161e0b788d593773b33006e01333946aa7e13:1_simple/SimpleSerial.h#L46

```
        boost::asio::serial_port serial;
        // [...]

        std::string readLine() {
        char c;
        std::string result;
        while(true) {

            asio::read(serial,asio::buffer(&c,1));
            switch(c)
            {
                case '\r':
                    result+=c;
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    result+=c;
                    return result;
                default:
                    result+=c;
            }
        }

        return result;
      }
```

As it is written there "code is optimized for simplicity, not speed". So I am thinking about optimizing this code. However I dont get any useful results. My general approach was this:

```
    void readUntil(const std::string& delim) {
        using namespace boost;

        asio::streambuf bf;
        size_t recBytes = asio::read_until(serial, bf, boost::regex(delim));
        [...]
```

'delim' would be "\n". But I do not know how to convert asio::streambuf to a std::string. Furthermore I do not know if I lose characters with this approach. E.g. if I receive the following chunk of text at once:

```
 xxxxx\r\nyyyyyyy
```

Would I just read 'xxxxx\r\n' and the rest is lost?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can access [the data](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/data.html) in `asio::streambuf` [directly](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer_cast.html), like this: `const unsigned char *data = asio::buffer_cast<const unsigned char*> (yourBuff.data());`
2. The data after the terminator won't get lost, but `read_until` [may read it](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until/overload1.html) into the buffer.

(Please note that all the above is documented in the Asio Reference, Tutorial, and Examples.)